# Probabilty question - multiple choice question with two correct answers

Tags: probability, statistics

There is a multiple choice question with 4 options and 2 right answers. One has to choose 2 options while answering. What is the probability of getting this question right?

My first instinct is to answer it this way: Probability that first choice is right (1/4) and the probability that the second choice is right out of the remaining options (1/3). The answer being (1/4)*(1/3)= (1/12)

The second way I am calculating: the total ways to choose 2 out of 4 = C(4,2)=6. Only 1 pair is the correct choice. So the probability is 1/6.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Alternative computation is $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{\binom{4}{2}} = \frac{1}{6}.~$ The denominator refers to the total number of ways of selecting $2$ items, without replacement, from $4$ items, where the order of selection is regarded as not important.  In general, for $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,n\}$, you have that $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k![(n-k)!]}.~$ See also [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Probability that first choice is right (1/4)

This is where you went wrong: Since 2 out of the 4 answers are correct, your probability of guessing right is **1/2**, not 1/4.

Assuming that you picked a correct answer for your first guess, there is 1 remaining correct answer among the other 3, so the probability of guessing correct is 1/3.

1/2 × 1/3 = 1/6, so this agrees with your other method.

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks Dan